# Yii2 ListView not display HTML

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have created a list view for a Quiz App. But it's displaying html.

[This is how it displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQodJ.png)

[Inspect elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8phuO.png)

My code:

```
echo ListView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            // 'format' => 'raw',
            'itemView' => '_view',
            'layout'=>'{pager}{items}{pager}',
        ]);
```

My _view:

```
<div class="quiz-answer">
<?php
    echo $model->title;
?>
<br/>
<?php
    echo Html::radioList($model->id, $model->user_answer, $model->answers, array('class' => 'question'));
?>
```

I have found a solution by using HTML::decode.

Thank you for all your suggestion and help.

Comment: can you inspect the element and take a screenshot and upload here?

Comment: updated . Please check, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using `Html::decode($model->title);`.

Comment: You shouldn't have encoded value in your model - this is straight way to complete mess and XSS as a result.

Answer (score 0):

You should `render` your template like this:

```
echo ListView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            // 'format' => 'raw',
            'itemView' => function($model){
                return $this->render('_view',[
                    'model' => $model
                ]);
            },
            'layout'=>'{pager}{items}{pager}',
        ]);
```

Comment: thank you for helping but it's not working :( i'm using this: https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-quiz, to build my quiz app, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

In `hereapp\modules\quiz\controllers\SiteController` of yii2-quiz title encoded `$answer->title = Html::encode($question->title);`

so the html tag in your title encoded.

you can comment it and submit your answer to check it.